# Equivalent expression for "Why buy the cow when you can get the milk for free"

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, tradução, português-europeu

In English we use the expression *Why buy the cow when you can get the milk for free* when we mean when we want the benefit of something without committing ourselves.

Does there exist any equivalent expression in Portuguese (in Portugal or Brazil)?

---

Em Inglês nós usamos a expressão *Why buy the cow when you can get the milk for free* quando queremos dizer que podemos nos beneficiar de algo sem precisar nos comprometermos.

Existe expressão equivalente em Português? (em Portugal e Brasil)?

Answer (score 2):

Já ouvi duas versões (Brasil) / I've heard two different versions:

> Para quê comprar uma vaca se eu só quero um copo de leite?

e

> Para quê comprar um porco se eu só quero um pedaço de linguiça?

Comment: Nunca ouvi nenhuma delas, nem em filmes dublados/adaptados e nem na rua. Pode ser algo regional (ao menos em São Paulo nunca ouvi)

Comment: Estas expressões são parecidas, mas não têm o mesmo significado que o original.